# Extending global mixin in Nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm on Nuxtjs 2.15.7 and I have a mixin file like this:

utils.js :

```js
import Vue from "vue"

if (!Vue.__utils__) {
  Vue.__utils__ = true
  Vue.mixin({ 
    data(){
      return{
         ...
      }
    },
    methods:{
      ...
    }
  })
}
```

I want to create another global mixin that extend my utils.js, for example:

utils-another.js :

```js
import utils from '@/plugins/mixins/utils.js'
import Vue from "vue"

if (!Vue.__utils__) {
  Vue.__utils__ = true
  Vue.mixin({ 
    // ... utils.js codes
    data(){
      return{
         ...
      }
    },
    methods:{
      ...
    }
  })
}
```

based on some env property i decide to use `utils.js` or `utils-another.js` . so how can I do that? I don't want to copy all utils.js codes to utils-another.js , that makes it hard for maintenance.

Comment: Can't you invoke or import `utils.js` into the other one? Or get it by the `window` instance or alike?

Comment: `utils.js` is a global mixin itself . I imported it into my other mixin, but how to merge two of them!! just importing will do the trick? I tried to use it as a mixin in the other mixin but got error. And about window instance, I use a universal (SSR) nuxt, so I will keep my distance from `window` instance as much as I can :D !! but if I have to use it, plz tell me how exactly it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can separate the mixin code this way

```
// example utilsMixin1.js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //...
    }
  },
  methods: {
    //...
  }
}

// example utilsMixin2.js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //...
    }
  },
}
```

**Thus, you can make two mixins global.**

```
// utils-another.js:
import utilsMixin1 from '@/plugins/mixins/utilsMixin1.js'
import utilsMixin2 from '@/plugins/mixins/utilsMixin2.js'
import Vue from "vue"

if (!Vue.__utils__) {
  Vue.__utils__ = true
  Vue.mixin({
    mixins: [utilsMixin1, utilsMixin2], // utils.js codes
  })
}
```

**or using only one mixin**

```
// utils-another.js:
import utilsMixin1 from '@/plugins/mixins/utilsMixin1.js'
import Vue from "vue"

if (!Vue.__utils__) {
  Vue.__utils__ = true
  Vue.mixin({
    mixins: [utilsMixin1], // utils.js codes
  })
}
```

> Use global [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) sparsely and carefully, because it affects every
> single Vue instance created, including third party components.

Comment: huh!! Never thought about that!! tanx alot :D